# saving an external data file using writeAllText

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, file, exception

I'm trying to save data to an external data file on visual basic using visualstudio 2013, so far I've found various methods to do this but they all get stuck on the same problem

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in >mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Access to the path 'C:\test.txt' is denied."

The current method I'm using is the following code

```
Dim filename As String
filename = InputBox("Please Enter a Filename", "Enter Filename", "")
    If filename = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please Enter a value to save", vbOKOnly, "Error")
        Else
        filename = "C:\" + filename + ".txt"
        File.WriteAllText(filename, "Accesories list Items")
    End If
```

Comment: the error message is pretty clear: the app does not have access to that file or folder.  Thats what User AppData folders are for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Windows C Drive is inaccessible by any external program (pretty sure MS programs can access it). Try using "C:\temp\test.txt" If that fails then there is a problem. Otherwise it's probably because you're not allowed to access that area of Windows.

Comment: thanks a lot i changed the path to the desktop and worked. thanks again for your quick responses.